# Marshalling C++ struct with union to C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct, marshalling

I'm trying to implement a C# wrapper around the Nikon DS-QI2 Camera SDK (only C++ dll available).

I am struggling with marshalling struct data, since the sizes are not matching.
The dll is working with pointers to struct arrays, so it is important to have the structures matching to retrieve the data from the pointer I pass to the dll method.

Everything was pretty ok before facing a union within a struct.
So as an example:

If I define the following struct in C++

```
struct CAM_Variant
{
    ECamVariantRunType  eVarType;
    lx_int32                i32Value;
    lx_uint32               ui32Value;
    lx_int64                i64Value;
    lx_uint64               ui64Value;
    double                  dValue;
    bool                    bValue;
    void*                   pValue;
    lx_wchar                wszValue[CAM_FEA_VARIANT_MAX];
    CAM_Area                stArea;
    CAM_Position            stPosition;
    CAM_TriggerOption       stTriggerOption;
    CAM_MultiExposureTime   stMultiExposureTime;
    CAM_Format              stFormat;
}
```

the correspective in C# would be

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct CAM_Variant
{
    public ECamVariantRunType eVarType;
    public Int32 i32Value;
    public UInt32 ui32Value;
    public Int64 i64Value;
    public UInt64 ui64Value;
    public double dValue;
    public byte bValue;
    public IntPtr pValue;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string wszValue;
    public CAM_Area stArea;
    public CAM_Position stPosition;
    public CAM_TriggerOption stTriggerOption;
    public CAM_MultiExposureTime stMultiExposureTime;
    public CAM_Format stFormat;
}
```

and both have a size of 664 bytes.

The problem is that the actual C++ struct implements a union

```
struct CAM_Variant
{
    ECamVariantRunType  eVarType;
    union
    {
        lx_int32                i32Value;
        lx_uint32               ui32Value;
        lx_int64                i64Value;
        lx_uint64               ui64Value;
        double                  dValue;
        bool                    bValue;
        void*                   pValue;
        lx_wchar                wszValue[CAM_FEA_VARIANT_MAX];
        CAM_Area                stArea;
        CAM_Position            stPosition;
        CAM_TriggerOption       stTriggerOption;
        CAM_MultiExposureTime   stMultiExposureTime;
        CAM_Format              stFormat;
    };
}
```

and sizeof(CAM_Variant) now returns 520 bytes.
While if I add Pack = 1 to the StructLayout attribute, the C# struct only turns down to a size of 657 bytes.

What kind of sorcery do I need to have the structures matching in the memory and in size, so that I can cast them in to my struct array?
Thanks!

EDIT: Extra related question.
Why the size of my full C++ struct is 520 bytes, while the size of the following is 516 bytes. Shouldn't they be equal since the array is defining the member with bigger size into the union? And since CAM_FEA_VARIANT_MAX = 512, the one below looks correct to me, while the other one not.

```
struct CAM_Variant_BIS
{
    ECamVariantRunType  eVarType;
    union
    {
        lx_wchar    wszValue[CAM_FEA_VARIANT_MAX];
    };
};
```

EDIT 2: It looks like it is the double adding 4 more random bytes, I do not understand why...

Comment: What about using the [```StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)```](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind?view=netframework-4.8) attribute on your struct with [```FieldOffset```](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attributes on the fields to match your C# pendant?

Comment: The structure in c++ has only two items 1) CAM_Variant (not sure the size, probably 32 bits)  2) Value : The union which is only up to 8 bytes.  Depending on the value of CAM_Variant  will indicate the size of Value item. lx_wchar is an array which is a 32 bit pointer.

Comment: @Shawn I am playing a bit with FieldOffset, but it is a pain when it comes to marshalling the string.

Comment: @jdweng I am not sure I fully understood your comment. Do you mean 1) eVarType? If it was like you say, the array only allocates a pointer, but that is not true since changing the array size changes the struct size too.

Comment: It is not changing the structure size.  It only looks like it does. The c++ code is WRONG.  It is a bug in c++ and probably working because the compiler is doing an alignment.  The array should not be lx_wchar which is two bytes.  It should be a 32 bit type.  The compiler is allocating the array immediately after the structure and probably is working by luck.

Comment: The c++ code is confusing, but will work as long as enough memory is allocated to handle the message size.  You can always allocate more memory than needed.  A wide character is 16 bits.  So in c++ the size allocated is the size of ECamVariantRunType + size of wszValue[CAM_FEA_VARIANT_MAX];  If CAM_FEA_VARIANT_MAX is less than 4 (4 * 16 = 64) than the size of int 64 is used unless CAM types are larger.  The 4 extra bytes are the size of ECamVariantRunType or the compiler is doing an alignment.

Comment: Consider using C++/CLI for this kind of work. Writing wrappers that expose the unmanaged guts as neat managed wrappers is vastly simpler there than trying to do it directly with C#.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the clarification, that cleared my mind a bit!

Comment: @JeroenMostert Actually that is what I'm trying to do right now. It's still giving me some strong headaches (especially when it comes to events and threads), but for the moment it looks like a better choice.